# How to store values from one Char arr[] to another char arr[] in c++?

Tags: c++

I have a character sequence with alphabets, integers and punctuations. After a `for` loop check, I want to separate the alphabets and store them in a new character sequence, but I cannot. I have tried various methods such as `strcat()`, `strcpy()` and currently trying a nested `for` loop method to store the value in new `char arr[]` but I am getting a logical error. I am new to C++ so I will be grateful if anyone can help me out.

```cpp
#include <cctype>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <string.h>
using namespace std;
namespace foo {int count =0; char str[] = "ad138kw+~!$%?';]qjj";}
int main()
{
    using foo::count;
    using foo::str;
    char str1[20];
    for(int i=0;i<=strlen(str);i++){
        char current=str[i];
        if(isalpha(str[i])){
            if(isupper(current) ? tolower(current) : current){
                count++;
                char temp=str[i];
                for(int j=0;j<strlen(str);j++){
                    if(str1[j]!=str[i]){
                        str1[j]=temp;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        else if(ispunct(str[i])){
            cout<<'1'<<"\n";
        }
    }
    cout<<str1<<"\n";
    cout<<"\t"<<count;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What do you expect `str1[i]` to be if `isalpha(str[i])` is false?

Comment: Start with indenting your code properly. It helps a lot.

Comment: Just use `std::string`.

Answer (score 1):

You can't directly do array2 = array1, because in this case, you manipulate the addresses of the arrays (char *) and not of their inner values (char).

What you, conceptually, want is to do is iterate through all the chars of your source (array1) and copy them to the destination (array2). There are several ways to do this.
For example, you could write a simple for loop, or use memcpy.

That being said, the recommended way for strings is to use strncpy. It prevents common errors resulting in, for example, buffer overflows (which is especially dangerous if array1 is filled from user input: keyboard, network, etc). Like so:

```
// Will copy 20 characters from array1 to array2
strncpy(array2, array1, 20);
```

Answer (score 0):

It's much easier to use a STL container for your task, a `set` or `unordered_set` is suitable here.

```cpp
#include <string.h>

#include <cctype>
#include <iostream>
#include <set>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
namespace foo {
int count = 0;
char str[] = "ad138kw+~!$%?';]qjj";
}  // namespace foo
int main() {
  using foo::count;
  using foo::str;
  std::set<char> alaphas;
  for (int i = 0; i <= strlen(str); i++) {
    char current = str[i];
    if (isalpha(current)) {
      alaphas.insert(current);
    } else if (ispunct(current)) {
      cout << '1' << "\n";
    }
  }
  cout << std::string{alaphas.begin(), alaphas.end()} << "\n";
  cout << "\t" << alaphas.size() << '\n';
  return 0;
}
```

The output:

```cpp
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
adjkqw
        6
```

Or more clear with range for

```cpp
#include <string.h>

#include <cctype>
#include <iostream>
#include <set>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
namespace foo {
int count = 0;
char str[] = "ad138kw+~!$%?';]qjj";
}  // namespace foo
int main() {
  using foo::count;
  using foo::str;
  std::set<char> alaphas;
  for (auto ch : str) {
    if (isalpha(ch)) {
      alaphas.insert(tolower(ch));
    } else if (ispunct(ch)) {
      cout << '1' << "\n";
    }
  }
  cout << std::string{alaphas.begin(), alaphas.end()} << "\n";
  cout << "\t" << alaphas.size() << '\n';
  return 0;
}
```